# Find the ratio of area of triangle axd and trapezium abcd?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

In trapizium abcd ab and cd are parallel sides.The diagonals ac and bd intesect at x .The ratio of area of triangle axb to that of cxd is 25:49 .find the ratio of area of triangle axd and trapizium abcd?

Dx/xb=cx/ax=5/7.......please help me...

Comment: Do you know the area formula $[ABC] = ab\sin(C)/2$?  There are other ways to solve the problem but this one is straightforward.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the areas of $\triangle ABX$ and $CDX$ be $25x$ and $49x$ respectively.

Since $\triangle ABX\sim\triangle CDX$,

$$\displaystyle  \frac{AX}{CX}=\frac{BX}{DX}=\sqrt{\frac{25}{49}}=\frac{5}{7}$$

We have

$$\frac{\textrm{area of }\triangle ABX}{\textrm{area of }\triangle ADX}=\frac{5}{7}$$

$$\textrm{area of }\triangle ADX=35x$$

and

$$\frac{\textrm{area of }\triangle ABX}{\textrm{area of }\triangle BCX}=\frac{5}{7}$$

$$\textrm{area of }\triangle BCX=35x$$

The area of the trapezium $ABCD$ is $25x+35x+35x+49x=144x$.

$$\frac{\textrm{area of }\triangle ADX}{\textrm{area of trapezium }ABCD}=\frac{35}{144}$$

In general, we have the following result:

Let $ABCD$ be a convex quadrilateral and $X$ be the point of intersection of its diagonals. Then we have

$$\textrm{area of }\triangle ABX\times\textrm{area of }\triangle CDX=\textrm{area of }\triangle BCX\times\textrm{area of }\triangle DAX$$

Furthermore, if $AB=CD$, then

$$\textrm{area of }\triangle BCX=\textrm{area of }\triangle DAX$$

and therefore,

$$\textrm{area of }\triangle ABX\times\textrm{area of }\triangle CDX=(\textrm{area of }\triangle DAX)^2$$